# What to drink with rattlesnake meat?

Tags: pairing

A friend is cooking rattlesnake.  What should she serve with it?  It is a competition - so the stakes are high (or should I say snakes are high!).

Here is the [link](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/78345/coffee-in-a-rattlesnake-recipe-why) to the whole scenario over on seasoned advice SE.

I thought of a nice cold beer - but are there any other choices out there?

Comment: @Ken Graham.  Sorry got distracted - I meant to thank you for your edits - thank you.

Comment: Having been suspended from seasoned advice for arguing with the mod over his edits, I don't know if the link will work...

Comment: Although you may not be able to see it, the link works.

Comment: @Dorothy.  many thanks for that...  stil workng hard, so will get round to cheesecake very soon - oh boy oh boy oh boy.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cooking with rattlesnake is truly an unique menu maker.

> Rattlesnake meat is a southwestern delicacy. If you haven't ever eaten rattlesnake, you are in for a real treat. No, it doesn't taste like chicken! It has a much gamier flavor, much more reminiscent of pheasant, frog legs, alligator, or even elk. - [Cooking with Delicious Rattlesnake Meat](http://www.streetdirectory.com/food_editorials/cooking/meat_recipes/cooking_with_delicious_rattlesnake_meat.html)

There are some out there that say rattlesnake meat tastes like chicken. Never having tasted rattlesnake meat, I cannot make a recommendation by personal experience. There was a restaurant here in town that once served python. I never tried it either, but they recommended having it with wine. The restaurant has moved on so I cannot say which wine they actually recommended.

That said I will go out on a limb and suggest a Shiraz or Chianti. I will use this as a suggestion:

> Wild duck, goose, partridge and pheasant meat is very aromatic and is paired with stronger, aromatic wines in comparison with the wines paired with domestic poultry. Choice of wine depends on the age of the bird and its preparation.
>
> Young roasted partridge or a pheasant has a less intense flavor compared to older birds so light red wine such as Shiraz or Chianti would be appropriate. If the meat is prepared with thyme, then a more mature red Burgundy would be more appropriate. - [Learn about wild game wine pairings](http://possector.com/menu/wild-game-wine-pairings)

Comment: Ah ha, Wow, many thanks, this may sound a bit dumb, but I had put wine out of contender, but I will pass on your thoughts (they have to be done by text as my friend has no internet where she is).  One thing I have never tried is elk - but there is always time!

Comment: @dougal2.0.0 While I won't/don't do snake, and think Ken gave a great answer, I'd suggest that tequila shots with lime and salt might also do it: 
breathe out, lick the salt, down your tequila shot and bite the lime.

Comment: @Dorothy Would you consider working your suggestion into an answer. It sounds good to me.

Answer (score 1):

Similarly, I haven't done snake (or lizard) but would think that tequila would pair well with a reptilian entrée. Like vodka, drink it neat and icy, straight from the freezer, or accompany your shots with salt and a lime chaser. Lick the area of your hand between the thumb and index finger, sprinkle with salt, lick the salt, shoot the tequila, chase by sucking on the lime wedge.  Any mezcal should do it, whether tequila (made from blue agave) or any of the mezcals made from the dozens of agave varieties.

Comment: The entree is for next month!